# Run Toast while ProgressDialog is running

Tags: android, progressdialog, toast

Is it possible to show Toast while ProgressDialog is running? If it is, there is some example about how to do it?

Thanks.

My current code that isn't working:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(
                        BotonesServicio.this, "Medidas",
                        "Comprobando datos");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(FacturasIFirmar.this,
                        "Trying to show toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .show();

                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: You should be able to do this as you would expect. Do you have any code that isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: context matters, it is possible when the context of both are same. First you should try.

Answer (score 2):

ProgressDialog "freezes" thread, therefore all other actions must be performed in a separate thread. You have to create your toast on the UI thread though.

Try something like this:

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //Calculations here
            try {

                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            toast.show();
        }

    });
    thread.start();
    dialog.show();
```

If you want to communicate with the UI thread, you should use AsyncTask or regular thread that sends messages to handler, which performs actions on the UI thread.

Good luck!